# Perl non-blocking user input

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Term::ReadKey;
ReadMode('cbreak');

while (1) {
    $char = ReadKey(-1);
    next unless defined $char;
    printf("Char: $char Decimal: %d\tHex: %x\n", ord($char), ord($char));
}
ReadMode('normal');
```

The above works great. But i want to be able to get user input while some executable is running. so i ve tried the below but its not working. maybe running an executable while trying to get a user input is messing up? if so, how do i go about doing it?

I am getting output from $myexe and depending on the user input, i would like to filter differnt things from $myexe

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Term::ReadKey;
my $myexe = 'bin/myexecutable';
open my $EXE,
    "$myexe distribute 2>&1 |"
    or die 'Cannot open EXE';

ReadMode('cbreak');
while (<$EXE>) {
    $char = ReadKey(-1);
    if (defined $char) {
        print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> $char\n"; #i would press a key but nothin prints out
    }
    print "$_\n";
}
ReadMode('normal');
```

Comment: What is the output of `bin/myexecutable distribute`?

Comment: @g.tsh bunch of strings. Example, "building <name>"

Comment: @g.tsh is the output of bin/myexecutable messing with me being able to get user input?

Comment: `while (<$EXE>)` is blocking. So the loop (and `ReadKey`) is executed every time the exe prints a line to `STDOUT`.

Comment: @g.tsh it prints multiple lines per sec. up to like 100 lines per sec. so ReadKey should work as if it is while (1) loop

Comment: @g.tsh i m not sure if Readkey uses STDIN and that 2>&1 | is interfering with STDIN? idk...

Comment: `2>&1` redirects `STDERR` to `STDOUT`, this part should be ok. I have executed this script. I have only changed `$myexe` to call `yes` and removed `print "$_\n";`. This works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @g.tsh yes that works for me too. hmm i wonder what it is about myexecutable that behaves differntly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70690/discussion-between-g-tsh-and-ealeon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wary of running a 'busy-wait' loop like you'd get with `Term::ReadKey`. But what I'd suggest - if you're trying to do two things at once - is that it may be worth considering doing a spot of parallel code.

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use Term::ReadKey;


my $myexe = 'bin/myexecutable';

my $filter : shared;


sub worker {
    open my $EXE, "$myexe distribute 2>&1 |"
        or die 'Cannot open EXE';
    while ( my $line = <$EXE> ) {

        #do something with filter here;
        print "$filter : $line";
    }

}

$filter = 0;
threads->create( \&worker );

my $keypress;
ReadMode 4;

while ( threads->list(threads::running) ) {
    while ( not defined( $keypress = ReadKey(-1) )
        and threads->list(threads::running) )
    {
        print "Waiting\nRunning:" . threads->list(threads::running) . "\n";
        sleep 1;
    }
    print "Got $keypress\n";
    $filter = $keypress;
}
ReadMode 0;

foreach my $thr ( threads->list ) {
    $thr->join();
}
```

This is some fairly simple example code - you can extend it in a variety of ways, but the principle is this:

- you start a thread to 'do the work'.
- you handle the 'keypress watching' in the 'main' thread.

Because there's a sleep in there, you're not busy-waiting on a keypress (e.g. polling as fast as a processor will spin).